# Use of "whenever" or "when" instead of "if" in logical sentences

Tags: word-usage, mathematics

The conjunction "if" is used a lot in scientific writing. I wonder if it is correct to replace it with "when" and/or "whenever".

For example, instead of writing:

> (1) **a · b = 0** if **a, b** are orthogonal.

writing

> (2) **a · b = 0** whenever **a, b** are orthogonal.

or

> (3) **a · b = 0** when **a, b** are orthogonal.

I read sentences like (2) and (3) in many scientific articles, but they were not written by English speakers, so I am not sure if they are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all equally correct and equivalent one-way statements of implication. In other words, none of them means the two way "iff".

They all say:

a, b are orthogonal **implies** a · b = 0

or

orthogonal(a,b) => a . b = 0

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me if the three sentences are also "natural" ? I mean that an English speaker would not find them weird. I ask because sometimes certain sentences are correct but no English speaker would ever say them.

Comment: Are they natural? Yes, they sound better in English that is not technical, **but** they are less the norm in math. You are improving on formulaic language. I wouldn't.